# Notes provide you with comments and asides >are< about the topic at hand - is "are" wanted here?

Tags: grammar

> Notes provide you with comments and asides about the topic at hand.

**...and asides are about the topic at hand**. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: So are the comments, probably. You can parse it as [(comments and asides) about the topic at hand] or as [(comments) and (asides about the topic at hand)]. Unless we expect the comments to be completely unrelated, they are probably also about the topic at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "aside" is often a tangential topic, it is put "aside" or "to the side" so as to not interrupt the flow of the main text.  It can also be an out of character comment, such as when a character in the play speaks directly to the audience.

A "comment" should be on topic.